# Why do I need so much memory for WriterT State?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

Trying to get to grips with the concepts I am trying to solve an exercise in Haskell using WriterT and State (it's [advent of code day 15](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/15)).  For some reason I do not understand I end up using loads of memory and my notebook (just 4G Ram) comes to a halt.

My first idea was to use strictness and sprinkle bangs around - but the issue persists.

Could someone explain me where I did go wrong?

Here's cleaned up code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Writer.Strict

main = do
  let generators = (Generator 65 16807, Generator 8921 48271)
      res1 = compute generators (4*10^7) 
  putStrLn "Answer 1"
  print res1

data Generator = Generator { _value :: Int
                           , _factor :: Int
                           }
    deriving Show

newtype Value = Value Int
  deriving (Show, Eq)

newtype Counter = Counter Int
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Monoid Counter where
  mempty = Counter 0
  mappend (Counter !a) (Counter !b) = Counter (a+b)

generate :: Generator -> (Value, Generator)
generate (Generator v f) = (Value newval, Generator newval f)
  where newval = (v * f) `mod` 2147483647

agree (Value a) (Value b) = (a `mod` mf) == (b `mod` mf)
  where mf = 2^16

oneComp :: State (Generator, Generator) Bool
oneComp = do
  (!ga, !gb) <- get
  let (va, gan) = generate ga
      (vb, gbn) = generate gb
      !ag = agree va vb
  put (gan, gbn)
  pure ag

counterStep :: WriterT Counter (State (Generator, Generator)) ()
counterStep = do
  !ag <- lift oneComp
  when ag $ tell (Counter 1)

afterN :: Int -> WriterT Counter (State (Generator, Generator)) ()
afterN n = replicateM_ n counterStep

compute s0 n = evalState (execWriterT (afterN n)) s0
```

I compile it with stack. The entry in the cabal file is:

```
executable day15
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             day15.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N 
  build-depends:       base
                     , advent
                     , hspec
                     , mtl
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

**update**

I had a little more time and followed the suggestion to make Generator strict.  However still something is using too much memory.

Here's the part of the prof file that I think may be relevant.

```
            Fri Dec 15 16:28 2017 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       day15 +RTS -N -p -RTS

    total time  =       71.66 secs   (71662 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 17,600,423,088 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE    MODULE    SRC                          %time %alloc

afterN         Main      app/day15.hs:79:1-36          41.1   20.0
mappend        Main      app/day15.hs:51:3-51          31.0    3.6
oneComp        Main      app/day15.hs:(64,1)-(71,9)     9.2   49.1
generate.(...) Main      app/day15.hs:55:9-42           8.5   14.5
```

Comment: If you're explicitly using `WriterT` and `State` in order to learn, then that may make sense, but otherwise, that particular puzzle can be solved with `unfoldr` and `zip`. FWIW, here's my solution: https://github.com/ploeh/advent-of-code-2017/blob/master/Day15/Solution.hs

Comment: If I didn't know any better, I'd suspect it's to do with `generate` rather than anything about the writer monad. But, really, I guess you need to actually *profile* it to find out where it's really taking the space...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid you are right that generate shows up heavy.  Do you have suggestions to make it lighter?

Comment: @bdecaf Making the fields of `Generator` strict would be my first guess, off the top of my head...

Comment: For a longer discussion on the way in which writer is lazy see https://blog.infinitenegativeutility.com/2016/7/writer-monads-and-space-leaks

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson thanks that hit the spot. I was just blindly expecting strictness is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is likely to be the `WriterT` layer.

Even the "strict" `WriterT` is *completely lazy* in the accumulator —it is strict in another sense unrelated to the accumulator.

For example, this program runs without errors:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Control.Exception

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let (x,_) = runWriter $ do
        tell $ Sum (1::Float)
        tell (throw $ AssertionFailed "oops")
        tell (error "oops")
        tell undefined
        tell (let z = z in z)
        return True
  print x
```

Furthermore, it is impossible to "strictify" the accumulator from within `WriterT`, because there's no way to get to it.

For long computations, thunks will accumulate and consume a lot of memory.

One solution is to store the counter in a `StateT` layer instead. The strict [`modify'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:modify-39-) function is helpful here.

---

Using `StateT` for an append-only accumulator is a bit unsatisfactory though. Another option is to use [`Accum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Accum.html#t:Accum) with judiciously positioned `BangPatterns`. This program throws an error:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Accum

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let (x,_) = flip runAccum mempty $ do
        add $ Sum (1::Float)
        add $ error "oops"
        !_ <- look
        return True
  print x
```

`Accum` is like a `Writer` that lets you access the accumulator. It doesn't let you change it at will, only add to it. But getting hold of it is enough to introduce strictness.